# Visual Studio 2013 signed/unsigned integer math behavior different when evaluating expression as function argument, compiler switch?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, argument-passing, integer-overflow, 16-bit

I'm porting a legacy 16-bit C program from the Windows 3.0 era. I'm using C++ for many reasons.
It makes some assumptions about math.

Let's say we have a function.

```
void myfunc(WORD addy);
```

Let's say I call this function like so:

```
myfunc((DWORD)some_integer - some_other_integer + (another_integer)*some_float);
```

In this case, the value should wrap-around below 0 to become 6690, but it gets passed as 0 - if it's important, this is passed into a .dll compiled in the same project.

However, moving that same exact expression with no variations into a variable like this:

```
WORD addy = (DWORD)some_integer - some_other_integer + (another_integer)*some_float;
```

EDIT: having (DWORD) in front still breaks it.

```
WORD addy = some_integer - some_other_integer + (another_integer)*some_float;

myfunc(addy);
```

results in the proper value being passed. The only difference is that the expression is evaluated outside of the function call and doesn't have a cast to DWORD in front of it.

This sort of behavior has led to more difficult-to-track-down bugs than I can try to describe.

Is there a compiler or linker switch to make it the default behavior not to pass 0 when evaluating an argument during a function call like this? And similar behavior other places, to enforce that -1 should be assumed to equal 0xFFFF (or 0xFFFFFFFF as the type may indicate)? Or is this a fundamental difference between C and C++?

Thank you.

EDIT:

This code was originally written in the Windows 3.0 days and has been compiled in Borland Turbo-Cxx products up to 4.5 and worked properly. The operator precedence nbelow

EDIT 2:

Here are the exact types in THIS case:

```
WORD addy = (DWORD cast)WORD_integer - WORD_integer_2 + (BYTE_value)*double_value;
```

**CONCLUSION EDITED**

According to IDEOne, C99 behavior differs from C++ behavior.
C99: http://ideone.com/KI6i7H
C++: http://ideone.com/gkQ5t2

Is there a compiler switch to change this to C99-style behavior?

Comment: Exact types of the different variables would be beneficial!

Comment: Edited - having (DWORD) in front still breaks it.

Comment: Edited with exact types & concluding question

Comment: Operator precedence is the same in C and C++. Can't say whether C++ did something different. Or if, for example, some overflow ends up behaving in a different way when you have 16 or 32 bits.

Comment: It looks like Dieter may have cleared it up some, but do you know if Visual Studio is exhibiting the correct behavior? Considering the state of Microsoft's C++ support in general, I am not necessarily inclined to automatically think it's better than Turbo C++ 4.5

Comment: I would CERTAINLY expect a compiler that is old enough to get a driving license to be LESS complete and less correct than one that has been around almost as long but updated every other year in between. Unless you are the first person in the world to try to mix integer and floating point math - which I kind of find rather hard to believe... I mean, it's not like you are exploring the outer reaches of the compiler's behaviour, right? If you were using the latest C++11/14/17 functionality in a really complex way, yes. But simple integer + floating point math should really have been debugged.

Comment: If you were to actually post some code with values and variables that we could compile, that shows your problem, we could perhaps compile it with multiple different compilers - that's usually a very good way to determine if it's a compile bug, since nearly always, compiler bugs don't "translate" to the same bug in multiple compilers [except for when the first lot compiler writers have misunderstood the spec and the next lot just copies what the first compiler does]

Comment: Posted links to ideone that replicate the behavior

Comment: Overflowing floating-point to integer conversion produces *undefined behavior* in both C and C++. In that respect the behavior is identical in C and C++. The difference you observe in your ideone code is probably caused by external factors (FPU setup) and has nothing to do with C or C++ at all.

Comment: You can run with the ball in both basketball and rugby...

Comment: @AnT at -O1 and higher, gcc and g++ 4.9.2 just send `0` directly to printf. Wild guess here, but perhaps its plan is to check the sign bit and send `0` if negative (because values between 0 and -1 are well-defined to give 0)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the exact values of your variables, but it is obvious that you are relying on a floating-point-to-integer conversion.

This conversion does not perform wrap-around for unsigned targets either in C or C++. Instead, it produces *undefined behavior* in both C and C++ if the truncated floating-point value is out of range of the target integer type.

I suspect that this is exactly what happens in your case: the source floating-point value is out of range of `DWORD`, which leads to undefined behavior.

If you want your value to wrap-around when converted to unsigned type, you have to convert the floating-point value to a sufficiently large integer type first, and only after that you can convert it to `DWORD`. If sufficiently large integer type does not exist, you have no other choice but the implement the desired behavior manually. Casts or implicit conversions will not help you with it.